# ¿Como crear colas Queue y eliminarlas correctamente en c#?

Tags: c#, poo, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

Mi maestra desea que resolvamos el siguiente problema con la creación de colas Queue:

1. Crear 3 colas(Empleado,No.De empleado,sueldo) de 100 espacios disponibles.
2. Insertar en colas hasta que el usuario decida cuando no.
3. Después de insertar; mostrar colas.
4. Enseguida buscar un empleado hasta que el usuario decida cuando no buscar.Si se encontró 
   mostrar: "Se encontró ", si no: "No se encontró"
5. Posteriormente: Eliminar valores de cola mientras el usuario lo decida. Mostrar que se esta eliminando(nombre,numero,sueldo).

6.Finalmente: Mostrar el contenido de las colas y cuantos elementos quedaron.

La cuestión es:***¿La forma en la que programe la solución es la manera correcta y la mas optima de hacerlo?,¿Como seria la mejor manera de programar la solución?***

**Clase main**:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int frente = 0, final = 0;
        string opcionInsertar,OpcionBuscar,opcionEliminar;

        Queue<string> Nombre = new Queue<string>(100);
        Queue<int> Numero = new Queue<int>(100);
        Queue<int> Sueldo = new Queue<int>(100);

        Program obj = new Program();
        obj.Insertar(frente,final,Nombre,Numero,Sueldo);

           do
           {
              Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
              Console.Write("\n");

              Console.Write("¿Desea ingresar otro empleado mas?Y/N: ");
              opcionInsertar = Console.ReadLine();
              Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
              Console.Write("\n");
                if (opcionInsertar.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                obj.Insertar(frente, final, Nombre, Numero, Sueldo);
                }
           }while(opcionInsertar.ToUpper() != "N");
       obj.MostarCola(frente, final, Nombre, Numero, Sueldo);

       obj.Buscar(Nombre);
           do
           {
             Console.Write("¿Desea buscar otro empleado mas?Y/N: ");
             OpcionBuscar = Console.ReadLine();
                if (OpcionBuscar.ToUpper() == "Y")
                {
                obj.Buscar(Nombre);
                }
           }while(OpcionBuscar.ToUpper() != "N");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("ACONTINUACION SE ELIMINARA EL PRIMER EMPLEADO: ");
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n");
        obj.Eliminar(frente, final, Nombre, Numero, Sueldo);

          do
          {
            Console.Write("¿Desea Eliminar otro empleado mas?Y/N: ");
            opcionEliminar = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("\n");
            if (opcionEliminar.ToUpper() == "Y")
              {
                obj.Eliminar(frente, final, Nombre, Numero, Sueldo);
              }
          }while(opcionEliminar.ToUpper() != "N");

       obj.MostarCola(frente, final, Nombre, Numero, Sueldo);
       obj.cantida(Nombre);
    }
```

**Estos métodos para saber si la cola esta llena o vacía , los escribió la profesora. Se que se pueden utilizar la propiedad .count donde inserto y elimino para no utilizar estos métodos.**

```
  public int ColaLlena(ref int frente)//saber si cola esta llena
    {
        if (frente == 100)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }  
   public int ColaVacia(ref int final) //saber si cola esta vacia
    {
        if (final == -1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
```

**Metodos para insertar y eliminar.**

```
    public void Insertar( int Frente,  int Final,  Queue<string> Nombre,  Queue<int> Num,  Queue<int> Sueldo)//INCERTAR
    {
        int x = 0;
        if (ColaLlena(ref Frente) == -1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cola llena");
        }
        else
        {
            x++;
            Frente++;

            Console.Write("{0})Infrese el nombre De empleado: ", x);
            string nombre = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("{0})Infrese el No.De empleado: ", x);
            int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("{0})Infrese el sueldo del empleado: ", x);
            int sueldo = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Nombre.Enqueue(nombre);
            Num.Enqueue(num);
            Sueldo.Enqueue(sueldo);
        }
        if (Final == -1)
        {
            Final = 0;
        }
    }
 public void Eliminar( int Frente,  int Final,  Queue<string> Nombre,  Queue<int> Num,  Queue<int> Sueldo) //metodo para eliminar
    {
        if (ColaVacia(ref Final) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("La cola esta vacia,No se puede eliminar");

        }
        else
        {
            if (Final == Frente)
            {
                string valor1 = Nombre.Dequeue();
                int valor2 = Num.Dequeue();
                int valor3 = Sueldo.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine("El empledo: {0}, con un numero de empleado: {1}. Y un sueldo de: {2}, ah sido eliminado!!!!!", valor1, valor2, valor3);
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.Write("\n");
                Final = -1; Frente = -1;
            }
            else
            {
               string valor1= Nombre.Dequeue();
                int valor2=Num.Dequeue();
                int valor3=Sueldo.Dequeue();
                Console.WriteLine("El empledo: {0}, con un numero de empleado: {1}. Y un sueldo de: {2}, ah sido eliminado!!!!!", valor1,valor2,valor3);
                Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.Write("\n");

                Final++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Finalmente; Los métodos para buscar, mostrar y contar en la cola.**

```
  public void Buscar( Queue<string> empleado)//metodo para buscar empleado
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.Write("Nombre de empleado a buscar: ");
       string nombre=Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------");

        Console.Write("\n");
        if (empleado.Contains(nombre) == true)
        {
            Console.Write("\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Se encontro empleado");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("No se encontro empleado");
        }
        Console.Write("\n");
    }
  public void MostarCola( int Frente,  int Final,  Queue<string> Nombre,  Queue<int> Num,  Queue<int> Sueldo) //metodo para mostrar 
    {
        string[] Noms = Nombre.ToArray();
       int[] emple = Num.ToArray();
        int[] suel = Sueldo.ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < Noms.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El empledo: {0}, con un numero de empleado: {1}. Tiene un sueldo de: {2}", Noms[i], emple[i], suel[i]);
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

    }
 public void cantida( Queue<string> nombre)//Metodo para contar
    {
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.Write("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("la cantidad de empleados que  quedaron en la cola es : {0} ", nombre.Count);
    }
```

> Se que como soy principiante, mi manera de crear, eliminar e insertar
>   en colas no es la correcta. Me gustaría que me dijeran cual es la
>   manera correcta y optima de hacerlo. De antemano,Gracias!.

Comment: Hola. Dado que esta pregunta es una revisión de código, debería estar en la web hermana de CodeReview (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) ahí podrán aconsejarte mejor sobre el tema, dado que esta página es para dudas técnicas, no revisiones.

Comment: Lo único que veo para mejorar es quitar lineas de código como los métodos para controlar la lista QUEUE, luego copias tu Lista a otra lista para recorrerla en el for, eso no es necesario y estas usando memoria duplicando las listas.